# typescript add color to winston logging levels

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, winston, definitelytyped

I'm trying to add colors to logging levels of winston. The output still has no color.

```
import { addColors , Logger, LoggerInstance, transports, AbstractConfigSet } from "winston";

let level = "debug";

const levels = {
        debug: 0,
        info: 1,
        warn: 2,
        error: 3
    };

const colors = {
        debug: 'blue',
        info: 'green',
        warn: 'yellow',
        error: 'red'
    };


export const log: LoggerInstance = new Logger({
  transports: [ new transports.Console() ],
    level,
    levels
});

addColors(colors);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redefine the level and colors, just pass `colorize: true` to you console transport:

```
new Logger({
    transports: [
        new transports.Console({
            colorize: true
        })
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
// for winston 3
var winston = require('winston');

const logger = module.exports = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
    winston.format.simple()
  )
});;;

logger.log('info', 'This is an information message.');
```

[source](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/examples/color-message.js)